# How to change the header style for salesforce standard pages

Tags: visualforce, standard-objects, css

Is there any way where I can change the header style of standard salesforce pages.  I have a hint where I can upload CSS into documents and that will change the header style.  Any body know about this ?

Answer (score 5):

First, create a new component:

```
Setup > Customize > Home > Home Page Components > New > HTML Area > Narrow
```

Enter "HTML mode" using "Show HTML" on the component editor. You can use the `<style>` tag to include the styles you want. You could also use JavaScript to load the style from a document or static resource, as in:

```
<script>
    var newStyleSheet = document.createElement("link");
    newStyleSheet.rel = "stylesheet";
    newStyleSheet.type = "text/css";
    newStyleSheet.href = "/resource/cssResourceName";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyleSheet);
</script>
```

Next, create a Home Page Layout, if you have not already done so:

```
Setup > Customize > Home > Home Page Layouts
```

Be sure to include the custom component, and also assign the layouts to all profiles.

After this, you need to enable custom sidebar components, if you have not already done so:

```
Setup > Customize > User Interface > Enable Custom Sidebar Components on all Pages
```

At this point, your style will appear on most pages (but not setup pages, reports, or Visualforce pages without a sidebar).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <apex:page controller="AdminController" standardStylesheets="false">

 <style>

.bPageHeader .phHeader td.right {

background-color:#FF0000;
}
.multiforce{
color:#FF0000;

}

</style>

 </apex:page>
```

In between  make your css

for ids,classes use browser inspect element

Comment: Where di I save the css? is it in documents?

Comment: In you custom page

Comment: If you are using statdard page means place it in homepage components

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @Sunny answer.
If parameter standardStylesheets="false" is acceptable, you can save your own styles as a static resource. It's easy to reuse and efficiently.

1. Prepare your css files and archive them in zip.
2. Create new Static Resource (Setup->Develop->Static Resources), upload the archive.
3. Use it in your custom page or SiteTemplate:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false">
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyStyles, 'styles/styles.css')}" />   
</apex:page>
```

"MyStyles" here is a name of the Static Resource. "styles/styles.css" is a path inside the archive.