# Override salesforce styles on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, stylesheets

I know that this question has already been asked before but none of these solutions does work for me.

So i have page like this

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="true" sidebar="false".../>
```

Note: i set showHeader="true" intentionally because i need it.

where i apply following styles

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.resources, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.resources, 'fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}"/>
```

The problem is that salesforce stylesheets override bootstrap stylesheets. And for example my button always looks ugly(IMHO). I have already tried scoped styles(`<style scoped> ...</style>`) and manually adding `link` tag to DOM with javascript but it had no effect.

I can't stand it anymore. Anybody please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Switch off the showHeader. This will switch off the Salesforce stylesheets by default.

Switching off standardstylesheet without switching off showHeader will still apply the style sheets.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately i need the header.

Comment: Then inline CSS can do the trick. It always worked for me. But with bootstrap I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, i have already tried inlining but it doesn't' work.

Answer (score 1):

I Found some similar posts with interesting answers:-

[How to ignore Salesforce CSS on VF Page (with header)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/how-to-ignore-salesforce-css-on-vf-page-with-header?rq=1)
[How to change the header style for salesforce standard pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20859/how-to-change-the-header-style-for-salesforce-standard-pages?rq=1)

If this helps,Please upvote!!

Thanks,
Vikas